# does the classification after a fft

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn, fft

I have a spectrum and I do the fft. And I wanted to use this data to make learning with scikit-learn. However I know what to take as explanatory variables, the frequencies the amplitudes or phases. It also seems it there's specific methods to process data. If you have ideas thank you

for example measurements made on two species

> measure for the specie 1

```
   Frequency [Hz]           Peak amplitude           Phase [degrees]
   117.122319744375         2806130.78600507         -79.781679752725
   234.24463948875          1913786.60902507         17.7111789273704
   351.366959233125         808519.710937228         116.444676921222
   468.4892789775           122095.42475935          25.5770279979328
   585.520239658112         607116.287067349         142.264887989957
   702.642559402487         604818.747928879         -112.469849617122
   819.764879146862         277750.38203791          -15.0000950192717
   936.887198891237         118608.971696726         -74.5121366118222
   1054.00951863561         344484.145698282         -6.21161038546633
   1171.13183837999         327156.097365635         97.0304114077862
   1288.25415812436         133294.989030519         -42.5375933954097
   1405.37647786874         112216.937121264         78.5147573168857
   1522.49879761311         231245.476714294         -25.4436913705878
   1639.62111735749         201337.057689481         -24.3659638609968
   1756.6520780381          77785.2190703514         29.0468023773855
   1873.77439778247         103345.482912432         -13.8433556624336
   1990.89671752685         164252.685204496         32.0091367478569
   2108.01903727122         131507.600569796         3.20717282723705
   2225.1413570156          62446.6053497028         17.6656168494324
   2342.26367675998         92615.8137781526         -2.92386499550556
```

> measure for the specie 2

```
    Frequency [Hz]           Peak amplitude           Phase [degrees]
   117.122319744375         2786323.45338023         -78.5559125894388
   234.24463948875          1915479.67743241         20.1586403367551
   351.366959233125         830370.792189816         120.081294764269
   468.4892789775           94486.3308071095         28.1762359863422
   585.611598721875         590794.892175599         137.070646192436
   702.642559402487         610017.558439343         -99.8603287979889
   819.764879146862         300481.494163747         -7.0350571153689
   936.887198891237         93989.1090623071         -52.6686900337389
   1054.00951863561         332194.292343295         4.40278213901234
   1171.13183837999         335166.932956212         92.5972261483014
   1288.25415812436         154686.81104112          -64.5940556800747
   1405.37647786874         91910.7647280088         82.3509804545009
   1522.49879761311         223229.665336525         -64.4186985300827
   1639.62111735749         211038.25587802          12.6057366375093
   1756.74343710186         93456.4477333818         25.3398315513138
   1873.77439778247         87937.8620001563         15.3447294063444
   1990.89671752685         160213.112972346         7.41647669351739
   2108.01903727122         141354.896010814         -48.4341201110724
   2225.1413570156          69137.6327300227         39.9238718439715
   2342.26367675998         82097.0663259956         -28.9291500313113
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Is Species 1 a set of data of one species, and you want to use the Frequency, Amplitude and Phase to learn to discriminate Species 1 vs Species 2?

Comment: @Henry this is just an example but I have 1000 species, I want from these data make classification algorithm

Comment: But what are you trying to do? You're trying to build a 1000 class multi-classification algorithm?

Comment: @Henry i have 2 class ,The especies are the individuals

Comment: I see. So you have 1000 'rows', and you have two classes. Each species contains like 60 features?

I mean the problem is kind of simple. You have to have... `Freq1, Amp1, Phase1, Freq2, Amp2, Phase2.....etc` with `Class={1,0}`. Then use something like a Decision Tree Classifier or a Support Vector Machine to classify it. I suspect the number of features you have against the training sample will make it quite hard to get good separation though

Comment: thank you i am testing @Henry

Comment: as warned I strongly suspect your results wont be great. But good luck to you anyway. You have quite a substantial amount of features for actually quite a limited data set

Answer (score 0):

OP is asking how to classify this. I've explained it to him in comments and will break it down more here:

- Each "specie" represents a row, or a sample. Each sample, thus, has 60 features (20x3)
- He is doing a binary classification problem
- Re-cast the output of the FFT to give `Freq1,Amp1,Phase1....etc` as a numerical input set for a training algorithm
- Use something like a Support Vector Machine or Decision Tree Classifier out of scikit-learn and train over the dataset
- Evaluate and measure accuracy

Caveats: 60 features over 1000 samples is potentially going to be quite hard to separate and liable to over-fitting. OP needs to be careful. I havent spent much time understanding the features themselves, but I suspect 20 of those features are redundant (the frequencies always seem to be the same between samples)